# Types of possible moves of tiling puzzle pieces

Tags: puzzle, tiling, dissection

This is a question about tiling puzzle jargon. What are the types of moving a tiling piece? I mean the single word or a phrase for rearrangement move of a piece. I would be grateful for proper mathematical names as well as contemporary English names. Suppose we are talking about 2D puzzle that lay on the table.

1. Sliding the item along the plane on the table without picking it up off the table, without rotating it. **Translate**.
2. Rotate the piece clockwise or counterclockwise without picking it up from the table **Rotate** or **Twist**.
3. **Flip** the piece to the other side, just like a pancake. It is necessary to take the piece off the table to do that. Here I found some inconsistency. It is also called **Twist** as in twist-hinged dissection. Flip sounds good but I have not found it in use. Instead, I found **Reflect** - reflecting the item in the plane as if being viewed in a mirror.
4. **Scale** up or down. This transformation is called **dilation** although I am not sure if both ways up and down.

I especially ask for the third type of move.

Reference:

http://www.mathpuzzle.com/Tessel.htm

[Move a polygon to a specified position using only allowed rotations, reflections, and dilations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300182/move-a-polygon-to-a-specified-position-using-only-allowed-rotations-reflections)

https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/gnf/book2.html

Comment: The first sounds more like *translate*. The third is - in 3d space - essentially the same as 2; so you may introduce definitions that use otherwise synonymous wors to distinguish them, e.g., call it *turn* or *turn over* (and make clear that you differentiate between *rotate* and *turn*). As you mention pancakes, why not use *flip*?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish for the pieces to stay the same size and shape (which precludes the dilation), then the motion taking one piece to another is an *isometry* of the plane. These [can be classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry#Classification) into four types:

- **Translation**, as you mentioned.
- **Rotation** about a point, again pretty self-explanatory.
- **Reflection** about a line, which roughly corresponds to the "flip" you describe.
- **Glide reflection**, which consists of a reflection followed by a translation along the line of reflection, and is shown in this diagram from Wikipedia:

[image]

A similar classification can be performed in higher dimensions, though the number of possible motions increases; a list for three-dimensional Euclidean space is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group#Overview_of_isometries_in_up_to_three_dimensions).

Comment: Glide reflection seems just a combination of two independent moves: Reflection + Translation. I do not see why you have put it as a separate move.

Comment: All isometries of the plane are just a composition of reflections, so by those standards one shouldn’t describe any other kind of motion. I’m classifying glide reflections separately because they are a separate kind of transformation of the plane, not equal to any of the other three. The given list isn’t a set from which to generate all planar isometries, it’s a complete list of every kind of isometry (if you count the identity as a translation or rotation by 0).

Comment: Your comment has not made it clear to me. I still see Glide Reflection as a compound action consisting of two basic actions. If you consider it as a basic action which cannot be expressed by two basic actions, then please explain it in your answer.

Comment: It is true that a glide reflection is a composition of two other motions on the list. But that’s not the point of the list! *Every* isometry of the plane can be formed just using reflections, which in turn can be expressed as a composition of glide reflections; there is no one true “basic” transformation of the plane, since any one of them is a composition of others. All I am doing is classifying the isometries of the plane by the type of motion they represent. Some of these are indeed compositions of other ones.